# Encountering issues adding basic left and right tap and hold controls in SpriteKit

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, uigesturerecognizer

So essentially what I am trying to accomplish is touch and hold controls in my SpriteKit game. I want to have it where I can move the player object in my game back and forth left to right dependent on which side of the screen the user is holding. In addition, when the user is no longer holding either one side or the other I want the player to natural make its way back to the centre of the scene. For example, if the user touches and hold their touch on the left side of the screen, the player moves towards that side. If the user however lets go or touches the other side of the screen, i want the player to move to the centre or other side correspondingly.

While I have been able to achieve some results of the matter with the code below, I have run into a few errors.

I want explicitly for the player to have to TOUCH AND HOLD either the right OR the left side of the screen not both at the same time, such not happening during runtime.

Sometimes, the player glitches out and returns to centre with an error about the touch recognizer not being able to evaluate touches being displayed in the debugger.

Any ideas how I can fix my code and achieve desired results?

```
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first!
    if player.contains(touch.location(in: self)) {
        if state == .inactive {
            startGame()
        }
    } else if touch.location(in: self).x < 0 {
        if state == .active {
            holdingRightControl = false
            holdingLeftControl = true
        }
    } else if touch.location(in: self).x > 0 {
        if state == .active {
            holdingLeftControl = false
            holdingRightControl = true
        }
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    if state == .active {
        holdingLeftControl = false
        holdingRightControl = false
    }
}

override func update(_ currentTime: TimeInterval) {
    if holdingLeftControl == true {
        let moveLeftward: SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: -240, duration: getDuration(start: player.position.x, end: -240))
        player.run(moveLeftward)
    } else if holdingRightControl == true {
        let moveRightward: SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: 240, duration: getDuration(start: player.position.x, end: 240))
        player.run(moveRightward)
    } else {
        let reCenter: SKAction = SKAction.moveTo(x: 0, duration: getDuration(start: player.position.x, end: 0))
        player.run(reCenter)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but something to try out might be changing the line

```
let touch = touches.first!
```

into

```
for touch in touches { }
```

This should help you find all of the touches.

Finding the last thing in the array might help as well.

I don't know about the sprite glitching to the center, but maybe you could find everywhere you change the location of the sprite.

I hope that helps and good luck!